# tikz/pgf: table below graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, pgfplotstable

Currently looks like:

[image: My graph and data table]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
% some text before...
Calciumcarbonat: \(m(CaCO_3)=M\cdot n=\SI{100,1}{\frac{\milli\gram} 
{\milli\mol}}\cdot n(CaCO_3)\).\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=\(t\) in \(\si{\second}\)]
            \addplot[smooth,thick] table[x=time,y=allvol] {myfile.dat};
            \addlegendentry{\(V\) in \(\si{\milli\liter}\)}
            % some more graphs
        \end{axis}

        \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={time,allvol,nco2}] {myfile.dat};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    Reaktiongsgeschwindigkeit zu Beginn %more text...
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I have put the whole construct in a minipage because there are two graphs, and I want them to display next to each other. Works nicely, but the layout of the graphs and tables and text below is messed up.

- Why is the table overlapping with the graph and the text below?
- Why is the text right below the graph and leaves no space for the table?

Any ideas on how I can fix these problems?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: You can try to wrap your `axis` and `table` in two `scope`s and provide a `xshift=...,yshift=...` options to one of them

Comment: Is there a reason that you typeset the table inside the `tikzpicture`? I would just put the table in a separate minipage right of the plot. Notice that it is impossible to really answer your question and test the answer since we do not have your data file.

Comment: To typeset stuff inside a `tikzpicture` it really has to be put inside a `\node`. But in this case you can do as suggested above, and place the table outside the `tikzpicture`, you probably don't even need a `minipage`.

Comment: @marmot that fixed it for me. Thank you a lot ^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved in the comments.